# How to call the events simultaneously in drag and drop event of multiple objects in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have totally 15 Movieclips in one array and another 3 Movieclips in another array. My goal is to drag one of the movieclip in the first array and need to set to another position. After setting position next event should be called, but my problem is that another movieclip can also accessible during the first event called.
Below I have attached the events in As3 Code:
//Assigned movieclips in array

```
goat_Array =[goat1,goat2,goat3,goat4,goat5,goat6,goat7,goat8,goat9,goat10,goat11,goat12,goat13,goat14,goat15];

tiger_Array = ["",tiger1,tiger2,tiger3];

for (p = 0; p < goat_Array.length; p++)
                {
goat_Array[p].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,goat_select);
                    goat_Array[p].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,goat_release);
                }
public function goat_select(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            /*var originalIndex = this.getChildIndex(current_goat);*/

            for (goat_count = 1; goat_count <= 15; goat_count++)
            {
                if (event.target == this["goat" + goat_count])
                {
                    this["goat" + goat_count].startDrag(true);
                    current_goat = event.target as MovieClip;                   
                }               
            }
        }
for (q = 0; q < tiger_Array.length; q++)
                {
                    tiger_Array[q].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,tiger_select);
                    tiger_Array[q].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,tiger_release);
                }
for (tiger_count = 1; tiger_count <= 3; tiger_count++)
            {
                if (event.target == this["tiger" + tiger_count])
                {
                    this["tiger" + tiger_count].startDrag(true);
                    current_tiger = event.target as MovieClip;

                }
            }
```

How to check these two events should be called and what are the conditons need to be checked to trigger both these event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but my problem is that another movieclip can also accessible during the first event called" What does this mean?

Comment: after goat event finished only tiger event should be accessed; but tiger is accessible at goat event  ; how to check goat event gets over?

Comment: Then in goat_release function add e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,goat_select); On that way current goat cant be draged any more

Comment: I have already did the same,bur i need how to start the tiger event function once goat function gets completed.Problem is I am getting able to drag both the goat and tiger in the start of the game, help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Delete this:

```
for (q = 0; q < tiger_Array.length; q++)
                {
                    tiger_Array[q].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,tiger_select);
                    tiger_Array[q].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,tiger_release);
                }
```

and insert it in goat_release function. In this way once the first goat is droped - tigers can be moved. But I'm still not sure what are you trying to accomplish...

Comment: Yes i did this but still not able to get the right solution. I am doing board game i.e., eg.chess game. My ultimate goal is to move the goat to new position after that only tiger starts to move. It as simple that in chess first white starts to move and then it completes is move, black starts to move. So like this is the concept of the game. help me in this.

Comment: Then in tiger_release function add for (q = 0; q < tiger_Array.length; q++)
                {tiger_Array[q].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,tiger_select);         tiger_Array[q].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,tiger_release);} for (p = 0; p < goat_Array.length; p++)
                {
goat_Array[p].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,goat_select);
  goat_Array[p].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,goat_release);
                } And also after you did as I tell you in the post just add  for (p = 0; p < goat_Array.length; p++){// goat_array[p] remove both listeners

Comment: Simply said in goat_release function you need to add listeners for tigers and remove for goats and in tiger_release add listeners for goats and remove for tigers

Comment: event.currentTarget is the current goat/tiger